# Must declare the scalar variable "@usrid"

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to compare two text values (login name & login password) with the existing values in sql db. While executing the below code, I receive a error as **Must declare the scalar variable "@usrid"**

Could someone help in this error please.

Im new to ASP.Net, C#.

---

```
protected void btnLoginTL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    string strtl = "Data Source=Server\\SQLER2;Initial Catalog=MTD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password='rro@123'";

    SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(strtl);
    conn.Open();
    string usrid = txtbxLoginNameTL.Text;
    string usrpswd = txtbxLoginPasswordTL.Text;
    string squery="Select usridmtld, passwordmtld from mobteldet.mobtellogin where usridmtld=@usrid and passwordmtld=@usrpswd";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = squery;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usridmtld", usrid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwordmtld", usrpswd);
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (sdr!=null && sdr.HasRows)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Telelist.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Enter correct user name & password");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using the **usrid** parameter in the query, but you are sending the **usridmtld** parameter when adding it.

Comment: I hope that in `Telelist.aspx` you also check the logged in user.

Comment: This is an extremely dangerous way of authentication, essentially asking for a hack - *Storing* and checking *unencrypted passwords* in a database, with administrator privileges and a hard-coded administrator password. Much worse, no authentication cookie or session variable is set which suggests `Teleist.aspx` is completely unprotected. Why aren't you using ASP.NET's built-in authentication mechanism?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Suggest me some link for ASP.NET's built-in authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding parameters with name:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usridmtld", usrid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwordmtld", usrpswd);
```

while in Your query parameters are conflicted, change your query:

```
Select usridmtld, passwordmtld 
from mobteldet.mobtellogin 
where usridmtld=@usridmtld 
and passwordmtld=@passwordmtld // note parameter variables
```

or change your parameters :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrid", usrid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrpswd", usrpswd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given column name in place of parameter.

*Change*

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usridmtld", usrid);
```

*With*

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrid", usrid);
```

Comment: Thanks Adil for your suggestion